# What does the statement x = '' mean in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am really new at this and I'm trying to learn python with MIT OCW course. At one lecture the prof wrote this code,

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    s = str(i)
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        s = ''
        if i % 3 == 0:
            s = s + 'Fizz'
        if i % 5 == 0:
            s = s + 'Buzz'
    print s
```

I know what the goal of this code is and pretty much understand what it's trying to do except for the `s=''`, but I'm really not sure what it does.

Comment: Set s to an empty string?

Comment: `''` is an empty string, but really you should ask the prof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, `s = ''` creates an empty string, but that doesn't answer the question of why it was done.

When you don't understand what something does, one possible strategy is to remove it and run the code. If you did that, you would get an error in subsequent lines when some other string is added to the empty `s` (`s = s + 'Fizz'`). You couldn't just have something like `s = 'Fizz'` in those lines (you could for the first, but not for the second), because you want to concatenate the strings when the number divides both 3 and 5. Creating the variable with the empty string allows you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The section of code on line 4:

```
s = ''
```

will set the variable 's' to be a blank string, but the variable is still set, so can be accessed later.

Your professor has chosen to do this, because to start with, the 's' is used to store the integer 'i', but then he wants to use it to store a string (either 'Fizz' or 'Buzz'), so has to clear it.

Answer (score 0):

That's nothing but the initialization of an empty string. After that, if the number is divisible by 3 it adds(concatenates) the word "Fizz" to the original string, which is empty so the final output would be only "Fizz"

If you want to explain more specifically, 
Take:

```
s = "this number is: "
```

Instead of:

```
s=""
```

It will give you idea of concatenation if you don't already know.